# How to access SSRS reports in ReportViewer using SQL Login with password credentials?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a web application where my SSRS reports are served up to the end users.

I had problems with the 401 unauthorized errors when I moved it from my local machine to the web server.

I found this was solved when I passed it my Windows account credentials, but this is not an acceptable long-term solution, as I will need to update the settings every time my network forces me to change my password, and this also puts my network login credentials into the web.config.

I have an SQL user login account created in the SSRS reporting database, with the same rights as my Windows account.

How do I get it to accept those credentials and how do I pass them?

Everything I've looked at talks about Windows authentication.  I have located the config file on the database server, and it is set up with the default RSWindowsNTLM setting.

So, if I have the USER set up on the MS SQL reporting database as

User:  reportUser
PW: reportUserPassword

How would that look? I'd prefer Visual Basic responses, but I can reverse engineer a C# solution.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turning SSRS from a AD authentication process to a SQL login Authentication is not something that can be easily answered on Stack overflow. it is a very long, and difficult process, isn't something that is available out of the box, and the set up is different for every version of SSRS. You'll be far better off googling online for details on how to implement this and reading the tutorials; there aren't many but some of them are very comprehensive. I haven't linked any, as you haven't tagged your version, but i'm sure you'll find at least one or two. Good luck, you'll need it I'm afraid.

Comment: @Larnu - "This is not a feasible approach" is a very useful response.  I'll set up a network user ID on the SQL server, with a password that does not expire, and add that user into the reporting database, perhaps, instead.

Comment: Wait,are we talking about the data sources here? I *assumed* we were talking about access to the portal. Using data sources with SQL Authentication is easy, and I can't explain how to do that.

Comment: No, we're talking about the reports, themselves, loading into the ReportViewer object on a web page, remotely. I don't have any problems connecting to the datasource, itself, for building the reports. My SQL login works fine for that.

Comment: Ok, so we are talking about pages like getting authentication to pages like http://YourSQLServer/Reports and not the reports themselves. Then my prior comments stands.

Comment: Yes.... which is why I found it very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: Did you get it working?  I'm trying to get an SSRS report server working over the Internet for users outside my domain, so I need to use SQL logins.  According to [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2793/sql-server-reporting-services-2012-permissions/) I'll have to redo my entire setup by reconfiguring my Data Source to use SQL Server Authentication, then redo all of my Datasets and Reports to use the reconfigured Data Source.  It looks like a huge amount of work.  I've Googled around as suggested by Lamu, but I don't see a lot of success stories.

Comment: The problem for me was that the original SSRS setup didn't have me with administrator rights, so I never saw the options for authorizing certain users and logins that others were talking about. I had to get our server vendor to upgrade my login/account status, and then that allowed me to authorize the report application "user" as having access.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but I connect to an SSRS server from within a WinForms application like this:

```
Private Sub PrintReport(ByVal ReportParameters As ReportParameter(), ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal domain As String)
    With ReportViewer1  'The Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer declared on my form
        'Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote
        .ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
        .ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)
        .ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://192.168.x.x/server")
        .ServerReport.ReportPath = "/SubFolder/" & ReportName
        Try
            .ServerReport.SetParameters(ReportParameters)
            .RefreshReport()
        Catch ex1 As System.Net.WebException
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to contact Report Server.  Check Link to Server", "NETWORK ERROR")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR GENERATING REPORT")
        End Try
    End With
End Sub
```

So it may be possible for you to use .ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials to specify a single login name for your application to connection to the SSRS server, but I'm not certain.  Maybe worth checking out.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer deals with a windows network identity, which I stated I have working now, but don't want to use. I want to use an SQL Server login identity. Your particular solution is one that is out there, and I am using that in the interim. Thank you for taking the time, in any case.

Comment: Can you not create a Windows login on the Server for your application then use this to connect via that user?  I suggested it only as it may be less work than converting the server to SQL login.  Good luck.

Comment: That's the route I am going to take, now that the feedback came that using an SQL login is not viable.  Since we already have SQL server logins created on the SQL server for data access, I was looking to avoid extra work if possible, and for continuity.  Sounds like that will be a lot less work, so I will create a Windows login on the server.